# How to manage several users requests at the same time in a telegram bot?

Tags: python

I wrote the first bot in my life using python, which get a username, password and some other data from user input, enter into a site and do some clicking there. It seems to be nothing complicated even for me whose experience in programming is only 2 months))) If the bot is used by one user from beginning to end, everything works well as it should, But if while the bot still has not finished working for one user and some other users are already beginning to use it, I have problems, global variables are confused and mixed.
Please help me to handle my bug (((

```
import telebot
from telebot.types import Message
from telebot import types
import requests


bot = telebot.TeleBot('xxx')


start_text = """
Hello

"""

payment_text = """
Chose the payment type:
"""

help_text = """
Commands:
/pushup - starting
"""

def check_reg(login, password):
    r = requests.post('xxx', data={'login': str(login), 'password': 
str(password)})
    response = r.text
    return response


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_handler(message: Message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, start_text)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def help_handler(message: Message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, help_text)



@bot.message_handler(commands=['up'])
def login_handler(message: Message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, a)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_login)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text_handler(message: Message):
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, b)


def get_login(message: Message):
    if '@' in message.text or '+' in message.text:
        global login
        login = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, c)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_psw)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, d)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_login)


def get_psw(message):
    global password
    password = message.text
    if check_reg(login, password) == '1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, e)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_up)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f)

def get_up(message):
    global up
    up = message.text
    if up.isdigit():
        if int(up) <= 0:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, g)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_up)
        else:
            get_url(message)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, h)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_up)


def get_url(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    key_xx = types.InlineKeyboardButton("xx", callback_data='xx')
    keyboard.add(key_xx)
    key_yy = types.InlineKeyboardButton("yy", callback_data='yy')
    keyboard.add(key_yy)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=i, reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    global url
    if call.data == "xx":
        url = "xx"
        test(call)
    elif call.data == "yy":
        url = "yy"
        test(call)


def test(message):
    test= test()
    if test.login(url, login, password):
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, j)
        if test.auto_click(up):
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, k)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, n)
            test.kill_task()
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, l)
            test.kill_task()
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, m)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_login)
        test.kill_task()

bot.polling(timeout=90)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by myself

```
user = {}

class user_cred():
   login = ''
    password = ''
    up = ''

def __init__(self, login, password, up):
    self.login = login
    self.password = password
    self.up = up

def set_login(self, login):
    self.login = login

def set_password(self, password):
    self.password = password

def set_up(self, up):
    self.up = up
```